# If $\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)$ then is $f$ continuous at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

For a function $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow R$, consider the following statements:

Statement 1: If $$`\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)`,$$then $f$ is continuous at $x=0$

Statement 2: If $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)=f(0)$$

Then which of the above statements is/are true.

***My Attempt:***

I feel that $\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f(0)$ is same as $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)$, so $f$ should be continuous at $x=0$. So statement 1 must be true.

In statement 2, since $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=f\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)=f(0)$. By same logic we can prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)=f(0)$

Can there be counter-examples to what I am thinking

Comment: I dont find any flaw in your argument.

Comment: take as $f$ the characteristic function of the rationals in $[-1,1]$; then $f(1/n)=f(-1/n)=f(0)=1$ but $f$ is discontinuous at $0$

Comment: Statement 1 is very very false .  Statement 2 is true.

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $0$ if and only if for *any*  sequence $a_n$ converging to $0$, $f(a_n)\to f(0)$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: Is $n$ to be considered restricted to the integers, or can it be any large real number?

Comment: It is a confusing fact of the notation that writing $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ we assume $n$ ranges through the integers, but writing $\lim_{x\to 0}$ we assume $x$ ranges through the real numbers.  Is this a fault of most elementary calculus texts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first statement

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0\;\text{ if } x=\frac{1}{n}\; n\in\mathbb{Z}\;\backslash \;\{0\}\\
\\0\;\; \text{if }x=0 \\ \\ 1\; \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

So $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)=0=f(0)$$

But $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{n}\right)=1$$

Hence for every $\lim x_n=0$ our $\lim f(x_n)\neq f(0)$

Hence statement is false

Second statement is obvious becouse of continuity of function

Comment: This depends on how you interpret $\lim_{n\to \infty}$.  If you take that  as $n\in \mathbb N$, as you would with sequences, then you are definitely. right.  But if you take $n$ as just the variable used in a continuous function, which should be viewed as a continuous variable approaching infinity....though it is bad form to use $n$ as a continuous variable.  It is impossible to tell OPs intent from the question.

Comment: Here $n$ is integer